# I am stuck in doing the UI Alignment Issue using selenium java

Tags: java, selenium

Query -
UI Alignment URL: https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/shifting_content/menu

Write an automation test script to test the UI alignment issue in the menu, the script should pass if there are no alignment issues else fail.

Being a beginner, I have used the mentioned code to verify the Alignment issue at pixel level. However, it is not displaying it. Do I need to use sikuli or something else? Please share the code if possible.

```
public class Who_Assignment_Test
{

 public static WebDriver driver = null;
 public static WebDriverWait wait = null;
 
@BeforeMethod
public void openApplication()
{
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\SeleniumProjects\\who-academy\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    
    wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
    //To navigate to url 
    driver.get("https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/shifting_content/menu");
    
}

@Test(invocationCount = 2)
public void uiAlignmentVerification() 
{
List<WebElement> items = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("ul li"));
if (items.size() > 0) {
  for (WebElement menu_item: items) {
   System.out.println(menu_item.getText());
   System.out.println("menu_item name: " + " " + menu_item.getText() + " " + "menu_item xcordi: " +  " " +menu_item.getLocation().x +  " " +"menu_item ycordi: " +  " " +menu_item.getLocation().y +  " " +"menu_item width: " +  " " +menu_item.getSize().getWidth() +  " " +"menu_item height: " + " " + menu_item.getSize().getHeight());
  }
}

driver.navigate().refresh();
{
List<WebElement> items1 = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("ul li"));
if (items1.size() > 0) {
  for (WebElement menu_item1: items1) {
   System.out.println(menu_item1.getText());
   System.out.println("menu_item name: " + " " + menu_item1.getText() + " " + "menu_item xcordi: " +  " " +menu_item1.getLocation().x +  " " +"menu_item ycordi: " + 
     " " +menu_item1.getLocation().y +  " " +"menu_item width: " +  " " +menu_item1.getSize().getWidth() +  " " 
           +"menu_item height: " + " " + menu_item1.getSize().getHeight());
  }
}}}}
```

Comment: Hope this will help you https://code.google.com/archive/p/fighting-layout-bugs/

Comment: I am unable to do it using the given link.Can you please suggest me how to write it.